# Python: How to extract float values from text file?

Tags: python, numbers, floating

I have content in a file like this and I want to extract only the float values from this. The text file contains new lines also and it should also be removed in Python.

```
hub,0.0166
cord,0.0166
ever,0.0332
switch,0.0498
sleep,0.06639
allow,0.09959

work,0.14939
```

I have tried this:

```
newDict = list()
for words in file:
    splitline = words.split()
    newDict.append("{0}\t{1}".format(splitline[0],log(float(splitline[1]))))
    newDict[float(splitline[0])] = ",".join(splitline[1:])
print(newDict)
```

the error I Observed is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Setups\Python\chi-1.py", line 11, in <module>
    newDict.append("{0}\t{1}".format(splitline[0],log(float(splitline[1]))))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

but I didn't got any output It showed me the error. The variable file in the loop contains the text file.So if anyone knows how to extract only the float numbers. kindly help with it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what is the error

Comment: You forgot separator: `splitline = words.split(',')`

Comment: The it showed error ---
` Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Setups\Python\chi-1.py", line 17, in <module>
    newDict[float(splitline[0])] = ",".join(splitline[1:])
ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Comment: Solved it. Thanks

Comment: @ForamKalyani you're welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is not a bigfile,

```
import re
with open('file.txt') as f:
    print(re.findall('\d*?\.\d+', f.read()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `csv` module to make it a little simpler:

```
from math import log

l = []

with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    csv_f = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in csv_f:
        l.append(log(float(row[1])))

print l
```

Output:

```
-4.09835258362
-4.09835258362
-3.40520540306
-2.99974029495
-2.71220883625
-2.30669352104
-1.90119494293
```

Answer (score 0):

**Split and `IndexError: list index out of range` Exception**

In `words` variable you get `hub,0.0166\n` value.

So `splitline = words.split()` is not work for you because default `split` use `space, \n, \t` to split string.

Use `splitline = words.strip().split(",")` to split string.

**Type Casting**

As first item from `splitline` is `string type`, so we can not convert to float.

`float(splitline[0])` is not correct statement.

**Variable Names**

1. `newDict`: You define `newDict` variable as `list`, give proper name to variable because according to name variable type is Dictionary, nut it is not case. Give name as `newList` or 'result_list' or any meaningful name.
2. You define `newDict` as list structure, and you assigning value like dictionary. 
   `newDict[splitline[0]] = ",".join(splitline[1:])` This will not work because `newDict` is list, not a Dictionary data type.
3. `file` : file is reserved word in Python, do not use such names as variable name.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are making is that your code assumes there will always be at least two items in each `splitline` list. This will not be the case if **a)** the line has no valid separators for the `.split()` function, or **b)** you have an empty row. As a result, `splitline[1]` returns the `IndexError` you are seeing.

As faost mentioned, you need to specify the separator for `.split()` to be `','`, as `.split()` uses a space as the default separator.

You mentioned that the text file contains "new lines", which I assume means empty rows? If this is the case, you need to account for that in your code. You can check the length of your list and make sure you only operate on it if its length is greater than 1:

```
new_list = []
for row in data:
  split_row = row.split(',')
  if len(split_row) > 1:
    new_list.append(float(split_row[1]))
```

This will extract all float values from your text file and store them as floats in a single list.